# Javascript code is not working inside the spring jsp

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, maven

I am a biginner in spring and i need to display something in spring using jquery.I have imported some necessary jquery plugins.But my problem is that the javascript code is not working inside the jsp.I have tested it by using an alert statement and some other thing,but none of them work.I don't know what to do.Below is my jsp code
index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4 /loose.dtd">
 <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title id="Description">In this demo the jqxTree is built from JSON data.</title>
<spring:url value="/resources/jqx.css" var="jqueryUrl" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${jqueryUrl}" type="text/css">
<spring:url value="/resources/jquery-1.js" var="jqueryaUrl" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jqueryaUrl}"></script>
<spring:url value="/resources/demos.js" var="jquerybUrl" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jquerybUrl}"></script>
<spring:url value="/resources/jqx_002.css" var="jquerycUrl" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${jquerycUrl}" media="screen">
<spring:url value="/resources/jqxcore.js" var="jquerydUrl" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jquerydUrl}"></script>
<spring:url value="/resources/jqxdata.js" var="jqueryeUrl" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jqueryeUrl}"></script>
<spring:url value="/resources/jqxbuttons.js" var="jqueryfUrl" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jqueryfUrl}"></script>
<spring:url value="/resources/jqxscrollbar.js" var="jquerygUrl" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jquerygUrl}"></script>
<spring:url value="/resources/jqxpanel.js" var="jqueryhUrl" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jqueryhUrl}"></script>
<spring:url value="/resources/jqxtree.js" var="jqueryiUrl" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jqueryiUrl}"></script>
<spring:url value="/resources/jqxdropdownlist.js" var="jqueryjUrl" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jqueryjUrl}"></script>
<spring:url value="/resources/jqxlistbox.js" var="jquerykUrl" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jquerykUrl}"></script>  <style>
.dark_overlay{display:none;position:absolute;top:0%;left:0%;width:100%;height:100%;
background-color:black;padding-bottom:500px;z-index:1001;
-moz-opacity:0.8;opacity:.80;filter:alpha(opacity=80);}.bright_content{display:none;
position:absolute;top:25%;left:25%;width:50%;height:50%;padding:16px;
border:16px solid #00ccff;background-color:white;z-index:1002;overflow:auto;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header" style="height:20%"></div>
<div id="content" style="float:left">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById('bttn').style.display='block';
            alert("hai");
                        });
    </script>
    <div id="jqxWidget">
    </div>

    <div id="bttn" style="display:none;"><input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="Add" /><input type="button" name="edit" id="edit" value="Edit" />
    <input type="button" id="delete" name="delete" value="Delete" />
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="lightbox-shadow"></div>
    <div style="top: 4096px; display: none;line-height: 1.5;" id="lightbox"></div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="light" class="bright_content"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a><div id="txtbx"><input type="text" id="itemNamess"></div>

    <div id="jqxDrp" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="ligtbx"></div></div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="fade" class="dark_overlay"></div>

</div>
<div id="footer" style="height:20%"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my servlet-context.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Map simple view name such as "test" into /WEB-INF/views/test.jsp -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

 <!-- Scan classpath for annotations (eg: @Service, @Repository etc) -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.gerrytan.pizzashop"/>

 <!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with 
   username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->
 <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
 destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
<property name="username" value="root"/>
<property name="password" value="kca@fnpl#12"/>
<property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
<property name="packagesToScan">
  <array>
    <value>com.gerrytan.pizzashop</value>
  </array>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <value>
    hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
  </value>
 </property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
</beans>
```

I think this may be a simple mapping issue.But don't know actually where the problem is.Please help me.

Comment: Have you added latest jquery.js?

Comment: i have used jquery-1.js version v1.10.2..is it ok?

Comment: Is there any error in browser's console?

Comment: i didn't noticed anything as error in console

Comment: is there any mapping issue?

Comment: I think there is problem with your JS url's just chick with it and one more thing why are you using  <spring:url>?

Comment: Use <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.js"></script>

Comment: i think in spring we need to use some tags to map the static files like .js/.css.That'ss why i used spring tags here

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.js"></script> this will not work in spring...

Comment: I am also using spring since last 2 year and it's working great for me.

Comment: i also used this <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.js"></script>..but it didn't works and showing the message that no mapping is found for those js files.I googled this and got the solution as using spring tags for mapping static files

Comment: if u know to map js files using <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.js"></script> please tell me.i will try that also

Comment: Please check ${pageContext.request.contextPath} what it is coming??

Comment: @ShoaibChikate how do i check that??

Comment: Print someover in your jsp code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/jquery.1.10.2.min.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/main.js" />"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>1. Test CSS</h1>

    <h2>2. Test JS</h2>
    <div id="msg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And your js and css file should be in resources folder.

Comment: no.its not working.Does i need to do any change in servlet-context.xml file??or need to do anything in pom.xml file?

Comment: In which folder you are containing CSS and JS files?

Comment: See the edited code and please make sure that your js files should in resources/jquery.js

Comment: actually the resources folder name is like src/main/resources.Whether i need to write like ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/src/main/resources/jquery-1.js ??

Comment: i think the above mentioned answer has the same effect like using the spring tags...i have tried that previously

Comment: Actually Java Resources folder contain 3 folder namely src/main/java,src/main/resources and src/main/webapp and i placed the js files in the src/main/resources folder

Comment: if i give the web path as src for these .js files it works.So its clear that the problem is in mapping the js files.